# Increment double-bracket PHP arrays to SQL

Tags: php, html, sql, arrays, variables

Here is a example of what my form looks like.

```
<div>
<input name="address[1][name]" type="text">
<input name="address[1][street]" type="text">
<input name="address[1][city]" type="text">
<input name="address[1][phone]" type="text">
</div>

<div>
<input name="address[2][name]" type="text">
<input name="address[2][street]" type="text">
<input name="address[2][city]" type="text">
<input name="address[2][phone]" type="text">
</div>

...
```

I'd like to increment the data obtained from each block in PHP and increment it into my database with MySQL.

What is the best way to achieve this ?
I know it generates arrays, but I do not know how to deal with the "double-bracket" method (the form "aaa[x][bbb]" probably has a proper name, which I do not know, I'm sorry).

Thanks.

Comment: The terminology you're look for is "nested associative array". I'm a little confused as to what you mean by increment? Are you talking about incrementing the KEY of the array? If so, for what purpose?

Comment: Do you mean you would like to loop over the arrays?

Comment: I'm sorry if I was not clear enough. Thanks anyway for the right terminology ! @Marcovecchio perfectly understood what I was trying to achieve.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to iterate over all fields using double brackets, the best structure to use are nested `foreach`'s:

```
$formdata = $_POST['address'];
foreach($formdata as $group)
{
  $SQLFields = array();
  $SQLValues = array();
  foreach($group as $field => $value)
  {
    // Here you have each individual field inside each group, so you can 
    // build the fields of the INSERT statement.
    $SQLFields[] = $field;
    $SQLValues[] = $value;
  }
  // Now assemble everything, and your INSERT is ready.
  $SQL = "insert into table (".
           implode(", ", $SQLFields).
          ") values ('".
           implode("', '", $SQLValues).
          "')";
  // Run the SQL statement the way you want.
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer ! It seems perfectly suitable for me. I will try to adapt this.

Comment: @Blackounet, no problem! If it works for you, please mark it as the answer to the question.

Answer (score 1):

I think you are looking for something like this:

```
$data = $_POST['address'];
foreach($data as $address) {
    //your address-object (name, street, city, phone)
    var_dump($address);
    //Add your sql-query in here and DO NOT forget to escape your received data
}
```

Comment: Thanks ! I'm not quite familiar with "var_dump", so I won't be able to try this code properly. Hopefully your answer will be useful to someone :)

Comment: `var_dump` does nothing else then printing the information in this variable out to you, so you can inspect it :)